# Windows style dialog in iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I would like implement Custom alert view in iOS like windows dialog style(with Yes,No,Cancel in horizontal) and I have to publish the app in Appstore as well.

Application will get reject from Appstore if I do this customisation?

Comment: Custom alert view won't reject by Appstroe. However, it may reject by the poor UI of the alert view, or the invalid content in the alert view and etc.

Comment: Can we customize UIAlertViewcontroller by adding icon to the title? And it will be accepted by Appstore?

Comment: Sure, you can do it and it won't be reject by Appstroe.

Answer (score 0):

The approval process in Apple Store, is quite complex, but there is nothing saying that customizing a view will get your app rejected.

[Check the guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for further information.